# How to show text only at specified times

Tags: javascript, time

I want to make some text visible between 3pm and 6pm and invisible otherwise.

THNX! IT WORKS!

Comment: There are time-functions available that you can use for checking. Just remember that the user can disable the JavaScript and see the text anyway.

Comment: But how.. I saw he used in javascript 'If {time=0}'

Comment: You can't reliably determine what timezone the user is in, but still: if you want to do this from JavaScript take a look at the methods of the [`Date` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).

Comment: you can use the pc time and specified time for timezones... and if you make a site for a specified country...

Comment: My point is that the user may not have the correct time set on their computer. Do you mean 3 - 6 pm _their_ time, or...?

Comment: You need to update in realtime or only when user refreshes the page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This solution uses jQuery:

```
var timeout = setTimeout(TimeCheck, 1000);

function TimeCheck() {
    var d = new Date();
    var h = d.getHours();

    if(h>=15 && h<18) {
     $('#message').show();   
    }
    else
     $('#message').hide();
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout(TimeCheck, 1000);
}
```

You can increase the timeout frequency.

**Updated based on comment**

```
<html> 
    <head> 
        <script> 
            var timeout = setTimeout(TimeCheck, 1000); 
            function TimeCheck() { 
                var d = new Date(); 
                var h = d.getHours(); 
                if(h>=15 && h<=18) { 
                    document.getElementById('message').style.display = 'block'; 
                } 
                else 
                    document.getElementById('message').style.display = 'none'; 
                setTimeout(TimeCheck, 1000); 
            } 
        </script> 
    </head> 
    <body> 
        <p id="message" style="display:none;"> Hoi </p> 
    </body> 
</html>
```

Comment: When does it hide? after the internet time of pc time?

Comment: Its the PC Time. If you want internet time of a particular timezone then you should use some service to get that information. For example http://www.timeapi.org/utc/now

Comment: I set it in the head as a script and gave the text id="message" but  it doesnt hide the text. or wont it work on localhost anyway?

Comment: You should hide the text on page load. Check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/tcqcejbe/

Comment: Have you included the jQuery script? It's not the same as JavaScript, really. (also, +1 for auto-update)

Comment: @Esli This answer uses jQuery. It will not work unless jQuery is included in your page.

Comment: You really don't need jQuery for this. The only part that needs changing is `$('#message').show();` and `$('#message').hide();` that can be changed to `document.getElementById('message').style.display = 'block';` and `document.getElementById('message').style.display = 'none';` to get same result exactly, 100% cross browser. @EsliStavenga FYI.

Comment: `<html>  
<head>  

 <script >  
var timeout = setTimeout(TimeCheck, 1000);

function TimeCheck() {
    var d = new Date();
    var h = d.getHours();

    if(h>=15 && h<=18) {
    document.getElementById('message').style.display = 'block';  
    }
    else
     document.getElementById('message').style.display = 'none';

    setTimeout(TimeCheck, 1000);
}
</script>  
</head>  
<body>  

<p id="message"> Hi </p>  

  
</script>
</body>
</html>
`this is my code now

Comment: That first one with `document.getElementById('message').style.display = 'none';` works.. Thnks! but now it always stops!

Answer (score 0):

```
var d = new Date(); // for now
var h=d.getHours(); 
if(h>=15 && h<18){

}
else{
document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'block';    
}
```

"id" is the id of your text from html you want to hide. 
You can understand why it is h<18. Because, 18:20 has a hour value of 18. But, You need it between 15 and 18.

Comment: You need to put getElementById function in //your code
Edited code, just check it